# Understanding JavaScript in detail: is it a class, a function, or just a variable?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am a beginner in JavaScript, and I am finding one concept very confusing. Consider the code below:

```
var person = {
     firstName   :"Penelope",
     lastName    :"Barrymore",
     // Since the "this" keyword is used inside the showFullName method below, and the showFullName method is defined on the person object,​
     // "this" will have the value of the person object because the person object will invoke showFullName ()​
     showFullName:function () {
         console.log (this.firstName + " " + this.lastName);
     }
​
 }
​
 person.showFullName (); // Penelope Barrymore
```

Is person a class or function or just a variable?

If assuming that person is a class, is the code `person.showFullName ();` the right way of invoking it, because in C# or anyother language we write

```
person perObj = new person();
perObj.showFullName();
```

?

Comment: I've always found that confusing too. And unreliable. I'm very curious to see the detailed answers, but my solution always: don't use it, and it won't bite you. I'd make a `function Person` and then a `person = new Person`. Sometimes all-static is good enough, and then I'd use `person.firstName` etc everywhere, so no `this`. Just an opinion of course.

Comment: What do you find confusing or unreliable?  The fact that objects can have methods?

Comment: In JavaScript you do **not** have classes (they can be simulated though). Here, objects inherit directly from other objects. You should read about JS prototypes.

Comment: Forget about classes as you know them from anyother language.

Comment: var person ... hint: var means 'variable' so what person could be?

Comment: @edc65 `var` could still be a variable pointing to a constructor (which is a class, a function _and_ an object).

Comment: @StefanBaiu has prototypical inheritance ever been used for anything else than emulating classical inheritance?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Prototypes were introduced in order to save memory space. One use case for prototypes is building a plugin architecture (think of jQuery.fn). Personally, I tend to move away from classical OO in JS. For the most part, I tend not to use `new`, `this` or `prototypes`. I try to favor composition over inheritance.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`person` is an object. It has 3 properties, named `firstName`, `lastName`, and `showFullName`. The first two properties contain strings. The last property contains a function.

When you call a function with the syntax `<expression>.<function>(<arguments>)`, where `<expression>` evaluates to an object and `<function>` is the name of one of its properties, then while the function is running the special variable `this` is set to the object. That's how `this.firstName` and `this.lastName` are able to access those properties of the object.

This feature is not very useful when there's just a single object, since it could easily just use the `person` variable. But you could use the same function for multiple objects.

```
function showFull() {
    console.log(this.firstName + " " + this.lastName);
}
var person1 = {
    firstName: "Penelope",
    lastName: "Barrymore",
    showFullName: showFull
};
var person2 = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Smith",
    showFullName: showFull
}
person1.showFullName(); // Penelope Barrymore
person2.showFullName(); // John Smith
```

Comment: @user5283721: When Barmar says "`person` is an object." he's simplifying a bit to avoid throwing too much at you at once. Now you've read his answer, we can say that `person` is a variable that *refers* to an object.

Answer (score 12):

Just to add to Barmar, you could have done something like this as well (in case you find it more similar to C#):

```
var person = function() {
     this.firstName = "";
     this.lastName = "";
} 

person.prototype.showFullName = function () { 
     console.log (this.firstName + " " + this.lastName); 
} 

var perObj = new person();
perObj.firstName = "Penelope";
perObj.lastName = "Barrymore";
perObj.showFullName();
```

Answer (score 6):

It's an object, not a class.

Consider it this way:

In other classical OO languages, when you instantiate a **class**,
you get an **instance**; and this instance is kind of equivalent to a JavaScript **object** -

JavaScript objects are dynamic "bags" of properties. It is a set of name-value pair and those values can be of any type - functions or object itself.

In your case, `firstName, lastName, and showFullName` are properites of person object.

You access the properties of an object using dot(.) notation,
for example: `person.firstName, person.showFullName()`

Answer (score 4):

`person` is actually an object literal in JavaScript. Object literals are those being defined as

```
var obj = {
    // Properties and methods
};
```

And their type is object. In JavaScript we don't have anything called *class*.

- *Everything* is an object. (even functions)

> An object literal is a comma-separated list of name-value pairs wrapped in curly braces. Object literals encapsulate data, enclosing it in a tidy package.

http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/object-literal/

---

Although we do have classes in ECMAScript 6, they aren't real classes as in other languages.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) says:

> JavaScript classes are introduced in ECMAScript 6 and are **syntactical**
>   **sugar** over JavaScript's existing prototype-based inheritance. The
>   class syntax is **not** introducing a new object-oriented inheritance
>   model to JavaScript. JavaScript classes provide a much simpler and
>   clearer syntax to create objects and deal with inheritance.

Comment: JS does not have real classes but there is a *class syntax*, so technically we do have *something* called class.

Comment: @StefanBaiu Yes, we've got a keyword called `class`, but this isn't used as regular classes as in other programming languages. In JavaScript we can only simulate role of classes by `new` operator and constructor functions (which are still of type objects).

Comment: @StefanBaiu So _everything_ is object except primitive types.

Comment: *Object literals* are syntax, not a type. And there's no such thing as a "literal object".

Comment: define "real classes". In what sense are javascript classes unreal?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I know. object literal is a syntax by which we  can define objects. Those aren't types. My sentences may be somewhat misleading. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @JanDvorak Those _"introducing a new object-oriented inheritance model to JavaScript"_. My mean by _real classes_ is that those of JavaScript are only a syntactical sugar over existing JavaScript's concepts and do not add any additional concepts to JavaScript. However those of object-oriented languages (such as Java, C#) are an independent concept and are introducing new inheritance model to the language.

Comment: @JanDvorak In JavaScript the only inheritance model is prototype based and was defined prior to ECMAScript 6, which `class` was introduced in.

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto: With ES6 `class` syntax, the inheritance is still object-oriented and prototype-based like in ES5. And the class concept was not unknown in javascript before, it only had no direct syntax. We've all used classes since the beginning - `new`, constructors, `.prototype` objects.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, you're right. My mean is that introducing `class` in ES6 didn't add anything to JS (Apart from syntactic stuff) as T.J. Crowder stated. Am I right?

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto: They did add the ability to subclass built-ins like `Array` which was not really possible before, but yes, they're mostly syntactic stuff.

Answer (score 2):

> Is person a class or function or just a variable?

JavaScript doesn't have classes. The variable person is a variable pointing to a memory location that holds an object.

The object itself has several aspects to it. There is a set of properties attached which are all attached to the person object. One of those properties contains a value which is function object. This function object contains an execution context.

The **[Execution Context<sup>ECMA</sup>](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3)** has a local environment, a lexical environment, and a this binding. The this binding points to the person object. The local environment of the function is scoped to declarations inside of the function, and the lexical environment of the function is scoped to declarations available to the Person object.

Answer (score 0):

`person` in your code is an `object`. In other words, `person` is an instance of `Object`, and `person` prototype is same as prototypes in other objects, created by `{}` initializer:

```
// Object initialiser or literal
person = {
  some methods and properties
}

// Called as a constructor
person = new Object({some methods and properties})
```

That means that your `person` object inherits Objects specific methods from prototype, such as `hasOwnProperty()`, `toString()`, `valueOf()`, etc.

Last written `Object constructor` can create not only "Hash-like" objects, but any other type of objects (Arrays, Strings etc.). All in javascript is objects, even primitives (they've wrapper objects, and have own constructors).

**Example:**

```
persons     = new Object([person_1, person_2, person_3])    
person_age  = new Object(18)
person_name = new Object('John')
```

We can write all of above expressions in other syntax:

```
persons     = new Array(person_1, person_2, person_3) //or      
persons     = [person_1, person_2, person_3]

person_age  = new Number(18) //or    
person_age  = 18

person_name = new String('John') //or    
person_name = 'John'
```

Strings and Numbers can be created using appropriate global object without `new`

[Page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects)

**New object type**

If need to create new type of object, must define new constructor function and define prototype (ECMAScript 5.1)

```
NewObjectType = function(arg1, arg2){
   this.arg1 = arg1 //define object's property arg1
   this.arg2 = arg2 //define object's property arg2

   private_function = function(){}
   this.public_function = function(){} //this function can't be inherited, because not in prototype
}

NewObjectType.prototype = {
   constructor : NewObjectType,
   public_inheritable_function_1 : function(){},
   public_inheritable_function_2 : function(){}
}

//creating new instance of NewObjectType:

my_new_object = new NewObjectType(arg1, arg2)

my_new_object instanceof NewObjectType //true
my_new_object instanceof Object        //true, because prototype was created with {} literal, and Object's prototype built into the prototype chain
```

**Explanation:**

When `new NewObjectType` is called, new instance of NewObjectType will be created. `Prototype` property of `NewObjectType` constructor function will be linked with hidden `__proto__` property of new instance.

**Object without prototype**

If need to create clear object without Object's methods, you must create it without prototype using create method:

```
person = Object.create(null)
```

It may be useful as simple key-value storage

**Type, that not inherited from Object**

If need to create new type of object without Object prototype in prototypes chain, you can use below syntax:

```
NewObjectType = function(arg1, arg2){}
NewObjectType.prototype = Object.create(null)
NewObjectType.prototype.constructor = NewObjectType 
NewObjectType.prototype.public_inheritable_function = function(){}

my_new_object = new NewObjectType(arg1, arg2)

my_new_object instanceof NewObjectType //true
my_new_object instanceof Object        //false
```

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript does not have classes or is not a class-based language. Instead, we say that it is a prototype-based language.

Comment: Well ECMA6 does have classes :P so your answer might not be valid now.

Comment: @Nirus: ES2015 (ES6) has `class` syntax. It's still prototypical inheritance, it's just another syntax for expressing that prototypical inheritance which reduces the complexity of setting it up properly if you want to use constructor functions.

Comment: @T.J i agree with you. But that has to detailed while the OP is a newbie to the language.

Comment: @Nirus: I think the concept of JS not having classes is one of the first things every newcomer to the language should understand.

Comment: @Nirus how is my response detailed when I actually gave the right answer?

Comment: @Leyth answer with an example as given by barmar for clarity. I wasn't the one who down voted your answer. I agree with your answer but i would expect better explanation illustrating an example that backs your statement.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: The concept of classes (and constructors) was always known in JavaScript - only those classes used prototypal inheritance, and JS is not a class-*based* language (where you need a class for everything). ES6 doesn't change much in that regard.

Comment: @Bergi: I know that, as you well know. Or rather, whether JavaScript has classes is a bit of a point of view thing. My view is that it does in any way that really matters, because the language is *that* flexible. The point is that either way, it's prototypical inheritance and the new syntax just simplifies setting things up. It's not that ES2015 added classes, it just added `class` syntax.